# Filter on nested serializer and Foreing Key Django/Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Following are my model classes

```
class ProductClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name')

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Product title')
    description = models.TextField('Description')
    product_class = models.ForeignKey(ProductClass, null=True, blank=True, related_name='products')

class ProductPriceRepository(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='price_repo')

    price = models.DecimalField('price of product', max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

    location = models.ForeignKey(Location,blank=True, null=True, related_name='price_repo')

    is_default = models.BooleanField()
```

This is how I have defined my view

```
class ProductClassList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        product_classes = ProductClass.objects.filter(products__price_repo__is_default=True)
        serializer = ProductClassSerializer(product_classes, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I have defined serializes as follow

```
class ProductPriceRepositorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductPriceRepository
        fields = ('price',)


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    price = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'price')

    def get_price(self, obj):
        for price in obj.price_repo.all():
            if price.is_default:
                serializer = ProductPriceRepositorySerializer(price)
                return serializer.data


class ProductClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ProductClass
        fields = ('name', 'products')

    def get_products(self, obj):
        for product in obj.products.all():
            for price in product.price_repo.all():
                if price.is_default:
                    serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
                    return serializer.data
```

Output looks like

[
    {
        "name": "Product Class Test One",
        "products": {
            "title": "Test Product One",
            "description": "",
            "price": {
                "price": "100.00"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Product Class Test Two",
        "products": {
            "title": "Test Product Two",
            "description": "",
            "price": {
                "price": "30.00"
            }
        }
    }
]

I am using SerializerMethodField to filter out default prices for a given product class Is there more efferent way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
class ProductClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ProductClass
        fields = ('name', 'products')

    def get_products(self, obj):
        return ProductSerializer(ProductPriceRepository.objects.filter(is_default=True, product__product_class=obj),
                                 many=True).data
```

Comment: the issue was `ProductSerializer` was receiving `ProductPriceRepository` object.  I made changes to `ProductSerializer` and that fixed the issue.